# smartGWT ListGrid JSON issue

Tags: json, datasource, smartgwt, listgrid

I have created a REST API at URL: `http://localhost:8888/rest/contacts` with this JSON output:

```
{
    "contact": {
        "address": [
            {
                "city":"Shanghai",
                "street":"Long Hua Street"
            },
            {
                "city":"Shanghai",
                "street":"Dong Quan Street"
            }
        ],
        "id": "huangyim",
        "name": "Huang Yi Ming"
   }
}
```

I want to print only the id value in a smartGWT ListGrid.

```
public class ExampleEntry implements EntryPoint {
    #Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();  
        dataSource.setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);  
        dataSource.setDataURL("http://localhost:8888/rest/contacts");
        dataSource.setRecordXPath("/contact");

        DataSourceTextField field = new DataSourceTextField("id", "id");
        dataSource.addField(field);        

        final ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();  
        grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
        grid.setAutoFetchData(true);  
        grid.draw();
    }
}
```

But it is throwing the following exception:

```
15:33:12.766 [ERROR] [jerseyexample] 15:33:12.747:XRP2:WARN:RPCManager:xmlHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() returned null
com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 15:33:12.747:XRP2:WARN:RPCManager:xmlHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() returned null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried searching google to find a fix but that did not help. Please let me know if anyone knows a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the data url, instead of using an absolute path use a relative one.

change

```
dataSource.setDataURL("http://localhost:8888/rest/contacts");
```

to

```
dataSource.setDataURL("rest/contacts");
```

This is also neccesary when you'll have to deploy it to a remote server.

I recommend you use a [RestDataSource](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/RestDataSource.html) instead of a plain DataSource, it has been designed specificaly for REST services, as you've said you use.

Using a RestDataSource is as simple as using DataSource.

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RestDataSource dataSource = new RestDataSource();  
    dataSource.setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);  
    dataSource.setDataURL("rest/contacts");
    dataSource.setRecordXPath("/contact");

    DataSourceTextField field = new DataSourceTextField("id", "id");
    dataSource.addField(field);        

    OperationBinding get=new OperationBinding();
    get.setOperationType(DSOperationType.FETCH);
    dataSource.setOperationBindings(get);

    final ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();  
    grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    grid.setAutoFetchData(true);  
    grid.draw();
}
```

You can map each OperationBinding with each http method (GET, POST PUT, DELETE) or whatever suits your REST API.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can put directly Xpath **in the field** you want to map

RecordXPath can be specified directly on the DataSource for a simple **read-only** DataSource only capable of "fetch" operations.

```
field.setRecordXPath("contact")
```